A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - Ha terminado la canalización
estoy usando el siguiente comando porque quiero importar una tabla de Excel a SQL
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..##NOMBRE_TEMPORAL1') > 0 BEGIN DROP TABLE ##NOMBRE_TEMPORAL1 END
SELECT *
into ##NOMBRE_TEMPORAL FROM
OPENROWSET('MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0','EXCEL 12.0;DATABASE=C:\Users\GABRIEL\Downloads\PruebaSQL.xlsx','select * from [PruebaSQLCSV$]')

Pero me sale el siguiente error:
Msg 109, Level 20, State 0, Line 2
A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - Ha terminado la canalización.)

Visite las siguientes paginas:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1355989/how-to-fix-a-transport-level-error-has-occurred-wh
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423494/getting-a-transport-level-error-when-executing-openrowset
Pero no me ha servido ya que sigo teniendo el mismo error
La tarea que necesito hacer es simple.
Importar una tabla de Excel a SQL mediante consultas, de esa manera podré automatizar los demás informes que tengo en Excel y así ahorrar tiempo, sin embargo, esto me parece una misión imposible ya que no me lo permite.
Algo adicional, brindé permisos de autotenticador a la carpeta donde guardo este archivo pero no funciona.

Esto ocurre porque el proceso está corriendo dentro de SQL Server y este se cierra al terminar de escribir los datos en la tubería, lo que provoca que se cierre, pero SQL server no los ha terminado de leer aún.
Para que no se ejecute dentro del proceso, debes configurar el proveedor para que no se ejecute dentro del proceso de SQL Server, sino fuera de él.
En el SQL Server Management Studio, expande el árbol

Server Objects

Linked Servers

Providers

Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0







Dá doble clic en este último y busca el valor en el diálogo que aparece:

Asegúrate que Allow inprocess no esté marcado y haz clic en OK.

Gracias por la respuesta @jachguate, te comento que pude resolver el inconveniente usando los comandos encontrados en el siguiente hilo
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62423494/getting-a-transport-level-error-when-executing-openrowset
Al parecer todo se trató de un error de sintaxis pues luego de volver a intentarlo linea por linea, se importó correctamente el excel.
Ahora bien, para aclarar que debo mantener las siguientes opciones con un CHECK
Dynamic parameter
Allow inprocess**
Disallow adhoc access
